# Is there any central control/access panel for several WordPress sites?

Tags: multisite, multisite-user-management, management

We have many WordPress sites on different hosts with different domain names.

Is there any solution for accessing all posts and settings with a central management tool?

It's been very hard for us to open 10 sites in 10 tabs and set one desired
configuration in all of them.

I know that WordPress has a version for Multisite, but this is this useful for multi site on one domain? Or can we use it to host different sites on one host?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For remote management of many installations of WordPress, I know of two options, one paid, one free.

> #### [ManageWP](https://managewp.com/about)
>
> ManageWP is a WordPress management console that gives users full power and complete control in managing virtually any number of WordPress sites in the easiest way possible.

> #### [InfiniteWP](http://infinitewp.com/about/)
>
> Manage multiple WordPress installations from a single dashboard using our free self hosted software.

---

As for **WordPress Multisite**, two references:

- **[Don’t Use WordPress MultiSite](http://halfelf.org/2011/dont-use-wordpress-multisite/)** - making the right choice
- and, from the same author, a very fine eBook for when you are going to use MS:

  **[WordPress Multisite 101](http://halfelf.org/ebooks/wordpress-multisite-101/)**

Comment: +100 to these two articles about multisite ... thanks a lot to you @brasofilo

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi, the kudos are for Mika, drop a cappuccino and a croissant in her tipjar ;)